# java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: sql-server, java, jdbc

I am having trouble connecting to my Microsoft SQL Server database through a jTDS connection:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433
    /MnA;instance=SQLEXPRESS", "sa","");
```

SQL Server is enabled, TCP/IP is enabled, Mixed server authentication is enabled.

Any ideas?

```
java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'sa'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:368)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2820)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2258)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:603)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:345)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.<init>(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at DB.dbConnect(testConnection.java:17)
    at testConnection.main(testConnection.java:7)
```

Comment: Are you sure the password is correct? Also, what's with the `/MnA` after `localhost:1433`? Further, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2011/03/02/getting-started-with-the-sql-server-jdbc-driver.aspx may be of use.

Answer (score 5):

You are attempting to pass in a blank password.  Odds are the sa account has a password.

You should create a separate account for the application to use instead of using the sa account.  Using the sa account is a major security issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a blank password.

1. Use `sqljdbc4 jar` file
2. Add this before your connection string:
   `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");`
3. Use this connection string for your jdbc connection:
   `Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=xxx","sa","pass");`